# Issue with determining if an element is present in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have an if statement in my program that is supposed to handle my reaction if  I'm directed to a page that asks for me to input an answer to a secret question during the login process. If I'm directed to this page, it should fill in the answer, if instead I'm directed to the password page, my program is supposed to continue running as normal. In order to handle whether or not I've been directed to the secret question page, I'm using an if statement to check whether or not an element on that page exists. Currently, I'm using the following:

```
if(driver.findElements(By.className("answer")).size() == 0){
    WebDriverWait pageLoadWait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);//wait for 10 sec.
    WebElement element1 = pageLoadWait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("answer")));
    WebElement answer = driver.findElement(By.name("answer"));
    answer.sendKeys(security);
    answer.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);       
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that when I'm not redirected to a secret page, but rather just to the password page, it's still looking for the `answer` class name, which doesn't exist.

I've also used `.isDisplayed()`, and received similar results, which makes me think it has something to do with the logic behind the if statement, but the fact that the program is still looking for `answer` even when it doesn't exist makes me think that it has to do with the way I'm checking for the presence of the element.

Answer (score 1):

The first `if` statement in the code snippet you posted would check for the element with class `answer`and if does not exist would check for the element with name `answer`. I think this should have been the opposite. I have modified the code with some improvements.

Selenium would check if you have set any implicit wait.If you have set an implicit wait (lets say 10 seconds), `driver.findElements` would look for the element every 500 milliseconds till 10 seconds.If after 10 seconds element is not found 0 is returned.

In the below code I am assuming that you have not set any implicit wait.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// wait for 10 seconds to see if the secret page has loaded.
int retryCount = 0;
boolean secretPageLoaded = false;
while (retryCount++ < 10) {
    if (driver.findElements(By.className("answer")).size()!=0) {
        secretPageLoaded = true;
        break;
    } 
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}

if(secretPageLoaded){
    WebDriverWait pageLoadWait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);//wait for 10 sec.
    WebElement answer = pageLoadWait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("answer")));     
    // You can remove the below line as the element will be returned in the above statement
    //WebElement answer = driver.findElement(By.name("answer"));
    answer.sendKeys(security);
    answer.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

When you use `findElements(By.className("answer")).size()` you are telling the driver to look for element with class name "answer", the driver can't 'know' that there isn't such element. You can try use `try catch` block

```
try {
    WebDriverWait pageLoadWait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    WebElement answer = pageLoadWait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("answer")));
    answer.sendKeys(security);
    answer.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
}
catch (TimeoutException) {
    // do something if you like
}

// continue...
```

If `pageLoadWait1.until` will find the element he will continue to `sendKeys`. If it doesn't the code will go straight to the catch (kind of `if else`).

Two notes

1. `WebDriverWait pageLoadWait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);` means
   the driver is waiting **up** to 10 seconds for the
   `ExpectedConditions` to be true, it might not wait at all if the
   condition is true (your comment is typo?).
2. `pageLoadWait1.until` returns the element you are waiting for, no need to look for it again.